# Forward slash interaction term in R

Tags: r, syntax, interaction

I'm reading [this vignette](https://lrberge.github.io/fixest/articles/fixest_walkthrough.html#interaction-terms) which states:

> Most R users will be familiar with the base expansion operators for creating model interaction terms, e.g. x1*x2, x1:x2, and x1/x2

I know that `x1:x2` is x1 multiplied by x2.

While `x1*x2=x1+x2+x1:x2`.

But I don't know what `x1/x2` is, and I can't find useful information online.

What does the forward slash do in interaction term in R?

Comment: From `?formula`: The `/` operator provides a shorthand, so that `a / b` is equivalent to `a + b %in% a`.

Answer (score 0):

The details section in the documentation for `stats::formula` provides a description for each operator, including `/`:

- The `/` operator provides a shorthand, so that `a / b` is equivalent to `a + b %in% a`.